# pagination is not working in wordpress main page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

hello there all i have a proplem that we are using one of the new themes called fancy theme the theme comes with a proplem in pagination now we are trying to fix that problem 
as you see here http://www.uniblues.com/ when you press page 1,2,3 it redirects you to the same page no change only the url changes too http://www.uniblues.com/page/3/or /4 , /5 according to the page number you press here is the code that the theme uses ..

```
<?php 
   //query_posts('paged='.$paged);
   $temp = $wp_query;
   $wp_query= null;
   $wp_query = new WP_Query();
   $wp_query->query('showposts=7');
   ?>
```

any ideas ?? .. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case if some body wants to now how i manged to did this i simply used this code and it's done ..

```
global $query_string;
parse_str( $query_string, $my_query_array );
$paged = ( isset( $my_query_array['paged'] ) && !empty( $my_query_array['paged'] ) ) ? $my_query_array['paged'] : 1;
query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=7&paged='.$paged);
                        ?>
```

and it works like charm .. thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Is it a theme we can download or did you develop it ?
The code you show get the last 7 articles, so the way it reacts is normal ^^

Here is, for example, the code used in twenty twelve :

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>
[...]
```

It simply use the `have_post()` function to get the articles, and use the template called content (content.php) to show them.
And the number of post to show is set in the administration panel > Settings > Reading.

If you are developing your own theme, you should take a look at how the base themes (like twenty twelve) work.

Comment: hello there sir thanks for your reply it's a theme that we purchased here is it's link : http://themeforest.net/item/fancytheme-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/3929323
** i think sir that you are not getting the proplem at the bottom you will see links for pagination 1-5 the proplem is when pressing them it should redirects you to the next set of posts 7-14 but it doesnt it only shows posts 1-7 in all pages .. hope iam clear ..**

Comment: although if you tested the theme here http://themeforest.net/item/fancytheme-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/3929323 you will find that it have the same bug .. thanks

Comment: Just in case : do you have the last version ? On the page you linked, there's a changelog of lasts versions saying : "Version 1.1: Fixed homepage blog pagination."

Comment: the theme author is not replaying to any one .. it's a common proplem :(

Comment: send me the index.php file at : ym [at] moonda . com (without spaces), I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
<?php 
// clear any other queries that may be in use!
wp_reset_query();
// check for $_GET paged value 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
// setup post arguments
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 7, 'paged' => $paged, );
// run our query
query_posts($args);
// start loop
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
  // if you use the <!-- more --> in your posts.
  global $more;
  $more = 0;
?>
   <div class="post">
      etc...
   </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="navigation">
   <?php next_posts_link(''); ?>
   <?php previous_posts_link(''); ?>
</div>
<?php else: ?>
   <div><h2>Nothing found</h2><p>No posts found for that query</p></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

:)